# Edit Facebook Post to Add Pictures

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I posted a status message on my Facebook page, but forgot to include a couple of pictures. Is it possible to edit the post that I made to add the additional pictures?

Comment: Why dont you juist delete and write a post again? Infact if you do this before facebook puts your status on friends wall, you have nothing to worry about old post. However as @mack said, It is not possible to edit post to include photos

Comment: I wouldn't want to do that if people have already commented on the photos. It is instantly posted on friends walls, so sometimes one cannot delete and recreate the post quick enough to avoid deleting comments/likes.

Comment: Hey @THEDOCTOR , if you are still looking for an answer, here is how you can do it.
Go to the post in your timeline.
There will be date underneath the title.
Do a right click and open in a new tab. Now Edit Post and attach Pictures.

Answer (score 4):

You can delete the post and recreate it with pictures. Or you can add the pictures on the comment section. Cannot add Images, you can edit text.

Comment: This is one of my biggest frustrations with Facebook, almost as bad as having to use "Publishing Tools" to add photos to page posts.

Answer (score 2):

No, its not possible. You can however add photos to the post via the comments section underneath the post

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly it's not possible through the web, but you can do it through the iOS app